# Exporting PowerShell Results In To CSV for Each User In The Domain That Last Changed Their Password

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a Powershell script that queries for the pwdLastSet attribute for every user in
the Active Directory domain. Essentially, the script determines when each user in the domain last changed their password. However, when I try and output the result using `scriptname.ps1 | Export-Csv "filename.csv"` it creates the file, however, I'm not getting the results I see in the console. I'm getting the following:

[image]

When I run the script without `Export-Csv` the results I desire display correctly.

This is the Powershell script:

```
Trap {"Error: $_"; Break;}

$D = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$Domain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.PageSize = 200
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"

$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl") > $Null
$Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://" + $Domain.distinguishedName

$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
ForEach ($Result In $Results)
{
    $DN = $Result.Properties.Item("distinguishedName")
    $PLS = $Result.Properties.Item("pwdLastSet")
    $UAC = $Result.Properties.Item("userAccountControl")
    # Retrieve user password settings to check if password can expire.
    $blnPwdExpires = -not (($UAC.Item(0) -band 64) -or ($UAC.Item(0) -band 65536))
    If ($PLS.Count -eq 0)
    {
        $Date = [DateTime]0
    }
    Else
    {
        # Interpret 64-bit integer as a date.
        $Date = [DateTime]$PLS.Item(0)
    }
    If ($Date -eq 0)
    {
        # 0 really means never.
        $PwdLastSet = "<Never>"
    }
    Else
    {
        # Convert from .NET ticks to Active Directory Integer8 ticks.
        # Also, convert from UTC to local time.
        $PwdLastSet = $Date.AddYears(1600).ToLocalTime()
    }
    "$DN;$blnPwdExpires;$PwdLastSet"
    
}
```

Comment: ```scriptname.ps1 | Export-Csv "filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation``` What does that do ? Looks like you are converting to csv. 
What does the console output look like ?

Comment: I get the image I posted at the beginning of the string length using `scriptname.ps1 | Export-Csv "filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: try ```scriptname.ps1 > "filename.csv"``` 
Can you give a little of what the console shows ?
What if you did ```scriptname.ps1 > $i``` then ```$i.gettype()``` what do you get?

Comment: ```C:\temp\Temp.ps1 > c:\temp\temp.txt``` worked fine for me with your script.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues on your code, the first one, `Export-Csv` is expecting an `object` or `object[]` as input and will convert it to `CSV` format, you're already passing a formatted semi-colon delimited `string[]`.

In this case you should use `| Out-File path\to\csv.csv` instead of `Export-Csv`.

> Do not format objects before sending them to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet. If `Export-CSV` receives formatted objects the CSV file contains the format properties rather than the object properties.

An example of what you're passing to the cmdlet and what it actually expects:

```
PS \> 0..5 | ForEach-Object{ 'asd;asd;asd' } | ConvertTo-Csv
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"12"
"12"
"12"
"12"
"12"
"12"

PS \> 0..5 | ForEach-Object{ [pscustomobject]@{col1='asd';col2='asd';col3='asd'} } | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';'
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"col1";"col2";"col3"
"asd";"asd";"asd"
"asd";"asd";"asd"
"asd";"asd";"asd"
"asd";"asd";"asd"
"asd";"asd";"asd"
"asd";"asd";"asd"
```

The alternative to this, and cleaner approach in my opinion, would be to cast a `[pscustomobject]`on each iteration of your loop and then pass the resulting array to `Export-Csv` (code below).

The other *possible* issue, assuming you're choosing the path of using `[pscustomobject]`, could be that `$Result.Properties.Item(...)` will yield an object of the type [`System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.resultpropertyvaluecollection?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) and you would need to convert it to `[string]` before passing the results to `Export-Csv` (also code below).

```
# Save the resulting pscustomobject array to the $output variable
$output = ForEach ($Result In $Results)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
    # All code should be as is up until:
    # "$DN;$blnPwdExpires;$PwdLastSet" => Remove this line
    
    [pscustomobject]@{
        DistinguishedName = [string]$DN
        blnPwdExpires = [string]$blnPwdExpires
        pwdLastSet = [string]$PwdLastSet
    }
}

# Then pipe the result to Export-Csv
$output | Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```